# How would you design email notifications for a threaded comments system?

Tags: comments

The current system features plaintext comments on pieces of content stored in a mySQL database, and I'm looking to add email notifications.

Current ideas:

- Emails to each user in the thread (no matter how deep)?
- Email only to the owner of the comment you are replying to?
- Email to content owner for each new comment? Only root level comments?
- Email only to users that check off a 'Notify me of replies' below each content piece, containing any new comment, threaded or not

Thoughts?

Comment: Have to select "Watch this thread" and sub-options of "[ ] Notify on comments to me", "[ ] Notify on all comments", etc. E-mail should be *batched* (e.g 4 times daily) and include summary.

Comment: As stated above, let the user choose.

Comment: Batching is a good idea, but also watch out if your provider has a limit on the number of emails their SMTP server will allow you to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with 2 settings that are changeable by the user:

```
Email me for any new root level comments       [X] On   [] Off
Email me for any new comment replies           [X] On   [] Off
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd design around the idea of notifications.

Users could pick which events they're interested in subscribing to, then indicate how they want to receive notifications by email.  This way, you can accommodate users who want no notification, as well as those who want notification by email, digest email, SMS, RSS, smoke signals, carrier pigeons, and telegraph.

Comment: See my answer above for how I implemented. I'd offer more, but my current carrier pigeon infrastructure needs some updating first.